# Unable to autoscale GCP instances using custom memory metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, autoscaling

I am trying to autoscale gcp instances based on memory metrics but I am unable to find the way how this can be done. I have tried to setup this through "stackdriver monitoring metrics" but no luck. Can someone help here how this can be done.
This is similar problem like posted on google forum but no proper answer here as well.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/X6LA0-8mFak

Answer (score 1):

It's required to install the Stackdriver Monitoring Agent by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent).
Once installed, you will get more options to [configure your autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-stackdriver-monitoring-metrics#configure_per_instance) from your [instance group page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceGroups/list)